# Is Sql syntax per DataBase engine (jdbc)

Tags: java, database, jdbc, sql

Assume that there is application that must interact with a DB of more than on type (i.e. MySql, MSSQL etc).  To do this. there is a layer between the application and the DB (whatever type the DB is) that is responsible to handle the interaction with the DB.  This layer has some parts that has, sql statements(hardcoded) of the type:

```
`"SELECT "+ obj.getName()+ "FROM TABLE_X WHERE NAME=?"` etc (trivial sample sql).
```

My question is, is the SQL syntax same in all Database engines (MySql, MSSQL etc)?  Which part differ?

I am asking this because I am partially working in an old project that does this and as far as I know it works.The sql statements are much more complex than the example including joins and updates.
I always thought though, that SQL syntax varies per database type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full supported database syntax varies between database servers.

However, a VAST majority support one of the two basic subset standards: ANSI SQL (Main [SQL standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Standardization)) and/or Transact SQL (MS SQL/Sybase "enhanced" version of ANSI SQL).

- Really basic SQL (SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE queries) are pretty much uniform.
- Features that are NOT directly SQL statement related might likely differ to a much greater degree (stored procedure calls, control flow statements, DDL syntax).
- Plus, every DB engine adds their own extra capabilities on top of vanilla ANSI SQL, from complete supersets (T-SQL, PLSQL) to minor additional abilities/keywords here and there (see `LIMIT/TOP` example in a different answer).

You should obviously stick to vanilla ANSI SQL if you want to make your SQL code as portable as possible, but which specific features beyond that you can use depends heavily on [which engines you want to limit yourself to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems).

Please note that the *prepared statements* (the "`?`" part of your example) have NOTHING to do with SQL syntax and are instead a property of the database connectivity APIs/libraries; as such they are as portable as your language's libraries (as well as individual database server's API they use) allow. The portability is obviously not as universal as that of ANSI SQL syntax but they are fairly widely supported.

Comment: @DVK:Do you mean that the type of sql statements they do in the project, let them get away with it?They are doing updates and joins

Comment: PLSQL is Oracle primary, but there's a lot of carry over into PostgreSQL.  MySQL doesn't have a name for it's extension of SQL.

Comment: @user384706 - I'm not sure I understand your question. The exact SQL in your example is 100% vanilla ANSI SQL and is supported by any RDBMS engine I can think of (again, I'm not talking about prepared statement technique of using "?" instead of a value whose support may vary a lot more). The general answer is "it depends entirely on specific SQL pieces they use"

Comment: @OMG Ponies - doesn't PLSQL support basic ANSI SQL as subset? I don't have enough experience with it to be sure.

Comment: @user384706 - re: question mark, please see the last paragraph. MOST APIs and database libraries are likely to support it but there's no guarantee that all of them will. YMMV and you should ask that for every individual engine. The search/question term you should use is "prepared statement".

Comment: Yes, PLSQL is Oracle's extension of SQL.  The info should be in the respective SO tag wiki, now that I think of it.

Comment: I just added in the post a trivial example. But they have more complex statements. So if they are using the basic ANSI SQL (i guess including joins??) they are correct in their implementation?

Comment: yes - just make sure they are using ANSI SQL joins and not TSQL ones (TSQL joins are not universally supported).

Comment: ANSI-92 JOIN syntax.  ANSI-89 JOIN syntax doesn't have OUTER JOIN support, which is why there are deprecated vendor specific syntax (like =* in TSQL, and (+) in PLSQL).

Answer (score 4):

The basics - SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE are consistent between vendors.  That includes aggregate functions (MIN, MAX, COUNT, AVG) and GROUP BY, HAVING and ORDER BY clauses.  Also, subqueries and UNION.

Beyond that, things get really sketchy.
String and date comparison/manipulation has some similarities, but generally very different.  ANSI helps, but the reality is no vendor implements the entire ANSI spec for a given year.  For example, SQL Server added analytic functions in v2005 but it's a limited subset (ROW_NUMBER, RANK, DENSE_RANK and NTILE) vs Oracle 9i+ support for LEAD and LAG besides the already mentioned.  PostgreSQL didn't support analytics until 8.4, MySQL still doesn't have any analytic support.  The other reality people gloss over is that the ANSI version might not perform as well as when using native syntax -- COALESCE on SQL Server is a good example, because it's slower/less efficient.  The list is just too big to cover all the differences -- containing to a specific data type helps, but then you need to know versions of the respective vendors...

Some databases named their extensions of the SQL standard/syntax.  Sybase and SQL Server's is Transact-SQL (TSQL), because SQL Server was originally built off Sybase.  Oracle has PLSQL, and PLSQL syntax is largely supported by PostgreSQL but there's still diversions.  MySQL has yet to name their extension.

Comment: What about more "esoteric" stuff? Informix? DB2? SQLite?

Comment: DB2 has analytic support, but I really don't know much about it.  I know less about Informix.  SQLite falls into the embedded realm of databases and has a lot of similarities to MySQL's syntax, but is limited.  It's hard to find people knowledgeable across so many vendors.

Answer (score 1):

Very basic SQL syntax like your example above is pretty much the same across all SQL databases, but once you start getting into joins and anything more complex there are quite a lot of differences.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Although basic functionality is similar, support for more complex features varies from engine to engine. If you want to get into the specifics, a good place to start might be by looking at the source code for [hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/)'s various [dialects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the syntax differs between DB Management Systems. For example in `MSSQL` there is a `TOP` construction, whereas in `MySQL` you'll have to use `LIMIT`. They also differ in basic thing like data types. Generally speaking the more complicated queries you write the bigger differences show up.

You might be interested in looking at [Comparison of relational database management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems).